# Block content type not showing up on homepage

Tags: blocks

I created a banner image I want to place on the homepage, I chose to place it in a block content type.  Everything is linked and saved correctly, but when I go back to the homepage the block isn't showing up. I went back and checked other sections that are set up the same way and copied there settings but even then the block still won't show.

Thoughts?

Comment: Check visibility by path or role. Path will be <front>

Comment: Have you cleared the cache? Include in tag your drupal version.